# Thread locks - When really needed?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have been using threads (parallel processing) and locks (prevent simultaneous manipulation of shared objects) intensively. Since I am writing code with a very high processing speed of parallel threads, receiving data and filling a shared data buffer, I am wondering when a lock is really needed?

- Writing a shared object
- Reading a shared object
- Updating a shared object given on its content

I understand that mainly the third situation is critical (given the famous "increment counter" example for threads and locks). But should I use locks in the other situations as well?

In my particular case its about a pandas dataframe used as a data buffer. I want to:

- add new data to it
- get data from it
- drop data from it (creating a circular buffer)

The below minimum working example (MWE) shows this process with threads, but processed sequentially for simplicity here, and intensive locking between the processes. Although this is a super cautious approach, I guess some of the acquire/release lock steps could be dropped? But since pandas is copying object when appending them, I am not 100% sure about dropping these locks.

Has someone tested this intensively or does anyone have any experience with it?

---

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import threading

thread_lock = threading.Lock()

df_data_buffer = pd.DataFrame({"key" : []})

def add_data_to_buffer(df_data_ingestion):        
    global df_data_buffer
    thread_lock.acquire()
    df_data_buffer = df_data_buffer.append(df_data_ingestion)
    thread_lock.release()

def get_data_from_buffer(key):
    thread_lock.acquire()
    df_data_buffer.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) #required for proper dropping by index
    df_extracted = df_data_buffer.loc[df_data_buffer["key"] == key].copy()
    thread_lock.release()
    drop_data(df_extracted.index)
    return df_extracted

def drop_data_from_buffer(df_index):
    global df_data_buffer
    thread_lock.acquire()
    df_data_buffer.drop(df_index, inplace=True)
    thread_lock.release()
    return True


df_data1 = pd.DataFrame({"key" : [1]})
t_add_data1 = threading.Thread(target=add_data, args=[df_data1])
t_add_data1.start()
t_add_data1.join()
print "*"*10, 1, "*"*10
print df_data_buffer

df_data2 = pd.DataFrame({"key" : [2]})
t_add_data2 = threading.Thread(target=add_data, args=[df_data2])
t_add_data2.start()
t_add_data2.join()
print "*"*10, 2, "*"*10
print df_data_buffer

key=1
df_data_extracted = get_data(key)
print "*"*10, "extract", "*"*10
print "df_data_extracted\n", df_data_extracted
print "df_data_buffer\n", df_data_buffer

print "*"*10, 3, "*"*10
df_data3 = pd.DataFrame({"key" : [3]})
t_add_data3 = threading.Thread(target=add_data, args=[df_data3])
t_add_data3.start()
t_add_data3.join()
print df_data_buffer
```

---

Output:

```
********** 1 **********
   key
0  1.0
********** 2 **********
   key
0  1.0
1  2.0
********** extract **********
df_data_extracted
   key
0  1.0
df_data_buffer
   key
1  2.0
********** 3 **********
   key
0  2.0
1  3.0
```

Comment: Any time a thread could be writing to a shared object, you need a lock. The only time you *don't* need locks is for concurrent access to a read-only object.

Comment: But this means I will always need a lock in my example. Process `add_data` definitely writes to it by adding rows, `drop_data` also manipulates the object by removing rows, and `get_data` needs to update the index, so also modifies the shard object?

Comment: Yes, mutable data is what makes concurrent processing hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [`locking discipline`](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/23-locks/) you choose matters on what kind of [`data consistency`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) is important to you. When executing a read, do you *need* the most recent data. For example, you could *choose* not to include locks when reading the dataframe, but only lock while reassigning it after some computation. However, it appears that you want full consistency guarantees, which your current locking discipline works well with. Furthermore, pandas DataFrame has no internal consistency guarantees when writing from multiple threads so you must lock while doing so.

However, you also must be aware that the `cpython` implementation uses a [`GIL`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), or global interpretor lock, allowing only one python 'thread' to execute at any given time. To get actual parallelism you would have to use [`multiple processes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which are liberated from the `GIL`. I doubt that the code above, due to this fact, executes any faster than running this operations in a single thread .

Comment: Yes I am aware of the `GIL`/`cpython` issue with "threads". I am in the situation of executing different processes in parallel (listening to messages of a MQTT broker tin a thread (`mqtt` module loop), adding data of received messages to the buffer in individual threads, main thread processing the data in given time intervals). Since it "fakes" parallel processing, I am fine with it. So far it seems to keep up with the speed of incoming messages in O(50ms) intervals. But I would like to reduce dead times due to locking and therefore try to reduce my lock acquire/release procedures.